Do expats get worse medical care than locals in Japan, and if so, what can they do about it?
I came across a Reddit comment by a man who goes by the handle “maritimelight”. His comment is as follows.

The idea that racism in Japan doesn't extend to physical violence is BS. Just google "Saitama+foreigner+family+murdered" for an example. There's also stuff about foreigners dying in prison here. Also, you should consider institutionalized racism like biased medical treatment a form of violence. The care I get here is vastly different from what my Japanese gf gets.

Looking through his history, it seems that he has been living and working in Japan for around 5 years. He can also write in Japanese, but I don’t know about his ability to speak it. Still, I get the feeling that he knows what he is talking about.
For those of you who are expats in Japan, did you get worse medical treatment than Japanese people did? If so, what did you do about it?

I voted to close as opinion-based. I cannot imagine how "worse medical treatment" is anything other than opinion-based.

It is opinion-based as David says. Anecdotally, I don't think my wife or I have had any worse medical treatment than we would have had in our home countries. Honestly, I think the treatment has probably been better over these past 9+ years.

@ProgrammingLlama: Well, I am glad to find out that your medical treatment has been good. I wonder if Mr. maritimelight has had the misfortune to get a doctor who is engaging in blatant double standards. If Japan had an equivalent of RateMDs.com, it would definitely make life easier for people trying to find a doctor in Japan.

The murder is not a hate crime. Biased medical treatment is mostly BS as far as I can attest to - even in the worst case where you do not speak the local language, many Japanese physicians have trained or done research in the US and it is not difficult at all to find a conversant, sympathetic doctor.
